# Is there a way to use Espresso functions outside of testing classes?

Tags: java, android, android-espresso

I want to develop an Android application which can simulate user interactions. For example the user types in a username and a password and a text. The app automatically goes on facebook, logs in with the given username and password and then makes a post with the text. For this I found Espresso. Is it possible to use the methods of Espresso outside of testing? If no, is there any other way of simulating user interaction with the android studio?

I already tried to implement Espresso in the `build.gradle` file like this: `"implementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2')` instead of `"androidTestImplementation"`. It worked finely i could use the methods in the main package but i get error when I try to use the methods: `"java.lang.IllegalStateException: No instrumentation registered! Must run under a registering instrumentation"`

Comment: Based on the exception, no.

Answer (score 0):

According to Espresso source code, it is relied on Android Test framework. 
- https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/testing/+/android-support-test/espresso/core/src/main/java/android/support/test/espresso/Espresso.java

This means, Espresso only can be invoked from `androidTestImplementation`. If not, it will be failed as you already had experienced.

For this reason, it's not possible in architectural point of view.